# C#: Why doesn't ShowDialog().ToString() return expected String?

Tags: c#, overriding, tostring, showdialog

labelTotal holds the value of class Keypad (C# WinForms).
ToString has been overriden to return labelTotal.Text.

```
namespace Gui3
{
    public partial class Keypad : Form
    {
        public Keypad()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public override String ToString() {return labelTotal.Text;}
        private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        ...
```

Why doesn't keypad.ShowDialog().ToString() return labelTotal.Text?

```
namespace Gui3
{
    public partial class Setup : Form
    {
        public Setup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void buttonStartDepth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Keypad keypad = new Keypad();
            ////////// Not working as expected /////////
            String total = keypad.ShowDialog().ToString();
            ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) method returns a [`System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) enum value, not the instance of your form. `ToString()` will be called on the enum value returned by this function.

You might try something like the following (assumes `keypad` will properly return `DialogResult.OK`):

```
private void buttonStartDepth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Keypad keypad = new Keypad();

    if (keypad.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        String total = keypad.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not calling KeyPad.ToString() you are calling DialogResult.ToString().  ShowDialog() returns a DialogResult.

Answer (score 2):

The method you are calling `ShowDialog()` actually displays the dialog

I think that what you want to do is

```
keypad.ShowDialog();
String total = keypad.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

ShowDialog returns a DialogResult, not a reference to the form.

Try changing to

```
String total;

if (keypad.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    total = keypad.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `ShowDialog()` twice?